# Color a graph so that every node is either colored or adjacent to a colored node

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, graph-coloring

Assume you have a connected undirected graph G. You want every node in G to be either colored or adjacent to a colored node. Design an algorithm to color the graph G appropriately. You are only allowed to color floor(n/2) nodes where n is the total number of nodes.

I made an attempt at a solution, but I identified that it doesn't fully solve the problems with the constraints, and I would like either a nudge or to be told that I'm on the wrong track.

My solution was basically to run BFS, and to color the nodes at every third "level". But I identified one instance where this fails -- just a linked-list of three nodes. If I color either the head or the tail, then one of the nodes will be distance 2 away from a colored node, and I am not quite sure how to guarantee that the middle node will be colored.

Comment: Consider ​ ​ ​ n = 1 ​ . ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: As a note, this problem is related to the [dominating set problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick a root and generate a spanning tree with, say DFS.

Then color the nodes in every 2nd level.  Choose to color either the even-numbered levels or the odd-numbered levels, according to which choice would color the fewest nodes.